# Member already defined + Windows Form

Tags: c#

I am getting 2 errors on a Tic-Tac-Toe program I am trying to create. 
The errors are as follows:
Error1:Type Game' already defines a member called 'Game' with with the same parameter types.
Error2:It is the same as above, but with Buttons_Click

My logic is that I am placing the form code in the wrong place.

```
{

public partial class Game : Form
{

    int counter;

    TicTacToe t1 = new TicTacToe();
    public Game()
    {
        counter = 0;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Buttons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 0, y = 0, current;
        string symbol;
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        switch (btn.Name)
        {
        }
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void Buttons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
int x = 0, y= 0, current;
string symbol;
Button btn = sender as Button;
switch (btn.Name)
```

{

Answer (score 1):

You define a method:

```
private void Buttons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Then later define another method:

```
private void Buttons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Just as the error states, you can't do that.  The same class can't have two methods with the exact same signature, the compiler would have no way of determining which one to invoke when it's used.

If there's only supposed to be one method, combine them into one.  If there needs to be two separate methods, give them different names.

(The same is true for the member `Game`, but the code shown doesn't show the second one.  It is a partial class though, so it might be in a different file.)

Answer (score 0):

`private void Buttons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 0, y = 0, current;
        string symbol;
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        switch (btn.Name)
        {
        }
    }`

you declare this kind of method twice. remove it and post again what happens.

Comment: Removing it allowed me to successfully build.

Comment: and then what? is your game working find now?

Comment: The form comes up, but nothing happens when I click the boxes. This is outside the scope of my original question. I believe I know what I did wrong though.

Comment: `Buttons_Click` i havent tried to see if this work? but can you 
do this :
`private void Buttons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){` `MessageBox.show("hi"); }` and then tell me if it is alerted when you click the boxes?

Comment: It creates more errors and wont build. Below is what I had written for the button clicking. 'if (t1.isEmpty(x,y) && !t1.Finished())
{
    counter++;
    if(counter % 2 == 1)
{
    btn.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
    symbol = "1";
    t1.set(x, y, 1);
    current = 1;
}
    else
{
    btn.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    symbol = "2";
    t1.set(x, y, 2);
    current = 2;

Comment: hmm,sorry. but do you think this `Buttons_Click` works fine? if the messagebox doesnt show, i think this is wrong `Buttons_Click`. Why not try to put your `program code` to one methos and call it to your `button1_Click` and `button2_Click` so forth.